# MySQL equivalent mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In MySql we can query like following to retrieve the data between _min and _max

```
select * from dummy_table where 10 BETWEEN _min AND _max;
```

Here is my mongo db data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a670cc6450867d5bf85f63e"), "code" : "S1", 
"_min" : 5, "_max" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a670cda450867d5bf85f63f"), "code" : "S2", 
"_min" : 12, "_max" : 20 }
```

I need to query like MySql equivalent for mongodb

Please suggest on this

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work

```
 db.test.find({"_min": {$lte:10}, "_max" :{$gte: 10}})
```